# Fortran pause function not working in Force 2.0

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm attempting to pause a FORTRAN code. When running it in Force 2.0, the code refuses to break. When running the code below:

```
1000 continue
     PAUSE 1
666 stop
```

I keep getting the following output from the console:

```
 PAUSE 1
        1
```

Warning: Deleted feature: PAUSE statement at (1)

How can I go about avoiding this ?

Comment: What is the underlying Fortran compiler for Force 2.0?  You can probably suppress the warning with an option.

Comment: The linked questions answer how to get rid of the warning. If you have other problem, like some incorrect behaviour of the code, you need to show more code ([mcve]). If your code does not pause on the `PAUSE` statement, you have to show more, the itself warning is not a problem, you can ignore it.

Comment: But it is a warning. Pause shouldn't be used in new code. What are you really trying to do?